# Remove Ubuntu Logo in upperleft hand corner of Gnome Classic

Tags: gnome, gnome-classic, logo

I really want to customize the bar at the top of ubuntu. My first "problem" is that I can't figure out how to change the logo in the upper left hand corner. Any ideas?

EDIT: I'm trying to change it to something else, just because I want it to not have any sign of Ubuntu at first look at my desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/apps/gnome-panel.css` file and remove the following line:

```
-PanelMenuBar-icon-visible: true;
```

[Source](http://mandriver.users.sourceforge.net/classic-gnome-guide.html)